# Number of ways to draw non-intersecting lines in a circle.

Tags: solution-verification

Given 10 points in a circle, in how many ways can you draw 5 lines so that all points are part of exactly one line and no line intersects another line?

An example of a solution can be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X8FG.png)

The solution according to a paper is 42, but the method to solve is unknown.

Comment: What have you tried? One case would be of chords joining adjacent pairs. What are other cases possible?

Comment: $10$ and $42$ are small enough numbers. One can just bash also.

Comment: I think while joining any 2 points to make a line, the 2 points should be adjacent, otherwise at least 2 lines will intersect with each other.